# Insert datetime into mysql java spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, forms, date, spring-mvc

I save the column `gioBatDau` in MySQL as datetime, in POJO as

```java
@Column(name = "GioBatDau")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)  
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") 
private Date gioBatDau;
```

I can't add data to the database:

```html
<form:input type="text" class="form-control" id="gioBatDau" 
   placeholder="Giờ bắt đầu" name="gioBatDau" path="gioBatDau"/>
```

Comment: Additionally, what is the error you are receiving? Copy and pasting your input does not help very much. It would help to see the controller as well.

Comment: What is the meaning of your `gioBatDau` field? Does that represent a moment, a specific point on the time line? Or does that represent a date and a time-of-day without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC? (Tip: Translating *all* your text to English is helpful when posting here on the English edition of Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Don’t use `Date` (not any of the `Date` classes). It’s a long outdated class and it was always poorly designed. For a timestamp use `OffsetDateTime` in Java and `timestamp` in MySQL. For all of your date and time work stick to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque I use gioBatDau to store information about the time of a movie screening. I am implementing a project to book movie tickets using spring mvc.

Comment: @cela it shows HTTP 400 error on browser
Type Rapport d'état

description The requirement is incorrect for the client.

Comment: In that case you are probably best off using `LocalDateTime` in Java and `datetime` in MySQL (Java `Date` is ill suited).

Comment: @OleV.V. i use tool to create pojos from mysql in netbeans

Comment: You can probably upgrade your tool to a version that supports java.time. java.time has been part of Java for nearly a decade now.

Comment: I tried switching to LocalDateTime and it said @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: com.ndh.pojo.Suatchieu.gioBatDau

Comment: I tried removing the @Temporal line but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Based on your new comments, you may need a custom converter for swapping between Strings and LocalDateTime.

Here is the converter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public final class LocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public LocalDateTimeConverter(String dateFormat) {
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(source, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // Log the error here
            // return null if you need the 400 error, or set a default date
            return null; 
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to register the converter. I am assuming you are not using Spring Boot, so you can register it in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like so:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateTimeConverter("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Column definition will look like this:

```java
@Column(name = "GioBatDau")
private LocalDateTime gioBatDau;
```

**Previous Answer and still relevant**

One option to resolve the issue you're facing is to switch the column type from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDateTime` and then specify the correct date-time format.

Here is the snippet:

```java
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class YourEntity {

    @Column(name = "GioBatDau")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime gioBatDau;

}
```

**Why Use java.time.LocalDateTime?**

Since Java 8, it's recommended to use java.time.LocalDateTime or java.time.LocalDate over java.util.Date for several reasons:

1. **Immutability**: Classes in java.time package are immutable, making them thread-safe.
2. **Rich API**: They provide a richer API for date-time manipulation.
3. **Clearer Semantics**: These classes have clearer semantics for dealing with dates, times, and time-zones.
4. **Time Zone Handling**: Easier to work with time-zones.

**Controller/Service-level Conversion**

While it's convenient to use `@DateTimeFormat` at the entity level, it's often considered better practice to keep entity classes as clean as possible. You can perform the conversion at the service or controller level. This makes your entity classes more reusable and decouples them from the web layer of your application.

For more information on the `java.time` package, you can read the [official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) .

Comment: Given the use of `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`, and the fact that "Giờ bắt đầu" apparently translates to "start time", I suspect that despite their choice of formatting pattern, the OP does *not* actually mean to use a date and time alone without a time zone or offset. I suspect `Instant`/`OffsetDateTime` along with a database column of SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is needed here.

Comment: I used LocalDateTime but it still doesn't work

Comment: @NguyenDucHung Could you show an example row or the DDL for the corresponding table?